# Заимствования = слова иностранного происхождения?

Tags: лексика, терминология

Заимствования и слова иноязычного происхождения — это одно и то же?

Часто встречаю толкование слов с пометкой "*заимств.*", если речь идёт о перешедшем в какой-то момент исторического времени в русский язык слове.

Answer (score 1):

Могу предоставить  по данной теме **справочную информацию из книги Е.В. Мариновой "Иноязычная лексика современного русского языка**". Учебное пособие, издательство "Наука", 2012 год.

Существуют **три термина**: иноязычное слово, заимствованное слово, иностранное слово. Они характеризуют лексическую единицу **с двух позиций:** **происхождение** слова (исконное или неисконное, что определяется лингвистами) и **восприятие** внешнего вида слова (фонетика, морфологический состав) пользователями языка.

Примечание. **Исконное слово** — слово языка, сохранившееся в **первоначaльном лексическом значении с древних времён** и  входящее в состав данного языка. Это индоевропейская, общеславянская и восточнославянская лексика, а также   собственно русская лексика – слова, возникшие с момента образования русской народности (с XIV в.) и рождающиеся в языке и в настоящее время.
Примеры: https://megaobuchalka.ru/7/28858.html

**Заимствованные слова** — это освоенные языком слова, которые по внешнему виду не отличаются от исконных слов (школа, лошадь, табак, солдат). С другой стороны, некоторые  слова, образованные в языке сочетанием исконного корня и иноязычного аффикса пользователи воспринимают **как иноязычное** (домофон, ультразвук).

Поэтому самым общим понятием является термин ***иноязычное слово***, которое включает в себя как **заимствованные** (освоенные) слова, так и слова, имеющие **признаки иноязычности** (такие слова обычно включают в словари **иностранных** слов).

Answer (score 0):

Заимствование может происходить из другого языка (то есть да, иноязычное) или из жаргона (профессионального или не очень).  Жаргонные слова сами могут иметь иноязычное происхождение — например, недавно обсуждавшееся "флудить".

Активизация слов, которые когда-то вышли из употребления,  и изобретение новых слов ("кенгурушная") заимствованием, видимо, не являются.

Comment: То есть заимствование есть также переход лексем из одного вида лексики в другой? Жаргонное -> книжное, специальное -> жаргонное. В таком случае понятие "заимствование" употребляется, когда речь заходит о рассматриваемом виде лексики (например, обсуждают врачебную лексику)?

Comment: Вряд ли жаргонное происхождение называют заимствованием. И диалектное тоже вряд ли. Или подскажите, пожалуйста, где Вы такое видели.

Comment: @grizzly про диалектное происхождение я не упоминал. А жаргоны как источники для заимствования сходны с иностранными языками.

Comment: [Жаргон — социальный диалект](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ruwiki/917608). Но речь не об этом. Я правильно понимаю, что в ответе Вы высказали свою собственную точку зрения? Об этом лучше сразу говорить, иначе создаётся впечатление, что Вы узнали это из авторитетных источников.

Comment: Вы правы, речь не об этом. Можете опровергнуть мое мнение с помощью авторитетных источников? есть общепонятные слова, смысл которых известен. Можно дойти и до дискуссий о значении слов "да" и "нет", это уже бывало.